# HIbernate with java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have these three tables.

want to make pojo class and hibernate configuration files but confused in relationship.

any help would be appriciate..

```
CREATE TABLE preprinttemplates (
  PRT_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  T_NAME VARCHAR(255),
  UPDATED_BY BIGINT(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PRT_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_User FOREIGN KEY FK_User (UPDATED_BY)
    REFERENCES user (USER_ID)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
PACK_KEYS = 1;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE preprintsubtemplates (
  PRT_SUB_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRT_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  T_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (PRT_SUB_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY FK_1 (T_ID)
    REFERENCES templates (T_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY FK_2 (PRT_ID)
    REFERENCES preprinttemplates (PRT_ID)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE templates (
  T_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  T_NAME VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (T_ID)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) to generate Hibernate Entities from a DB Schema (via Eclipse or Ant)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like two parent-child, 1:m relationships to me: template->pre-print template and pre-print template->pre-print sub-template.

So you'll have three Java classes.  The ones for `Template` and `PrePrintTemplate` will have children `List<PrePrintTemplate>` and `List<PrePrintSubTemplate>`, respectively.

Comment: Sometimes I don't always have the time to provide a complete answer; I wouldn't call someone lazy when they were just pressed for time.  Your answer is good, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can write pojo class and drectly map into database

code will be like this..

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "preprinttemplates")
public class PrintTemplateModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PRT_ID")
    private int PRT_ID;
    @Column(name = "T_NAME")
       private String T_NAME;
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
       private int UPDATED_BY;
            }
```

then generate getters and setters for this class.
hope this will help you.